# Optimize code for profanity filter

Tags: javascript

I have a chat app and I want to use a profanity filter.

I've came up with: http://jsfiddle.net/691nruoL/4/

```
var chatMessage = "sex it up what the fuck tits lol fuck titsss";

// Potentially an array of hundreds of words coming from a JSON file
var badWords = ['sex', 'fUck', 'dick', 'penis', 'cum', 'tits', 'fuck'];

for (var i = 0; i < badWords.length; i++) {
    if (chatMessage.indexOf(badWords[i].toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
        chatMessage = chatMessage.replace(badWords[i].toLowerCase(), pushAsterisksForWordLength(badWords[i].length));
    }
}

function pushAsterisksForWordLength(asterisksLength) {
    var censoredWordArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < asterisksLength; i++) {
        censoredWordArray.push('*');
    }
    return censoredWordArray.join('');
}

console.log(chatMessage);
```

How would you optimize it? I feel like with many bad words in the array, it could be quite slow.

Comment: You "feel like" it could be slow? Have you actually measured it?

Comment: ~ 0.5s to 1s, on chrome 64-bit and a good computer.

Comment: That's 0.5 **ms**. Milliseconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subsitiutes each letter in a "bad" word with an asterisk without looping over the word:

```
chatMessage.replace(/sex|fuck|tits/gi,function( word ){
 return word.replace(/./g,'*')
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/691nruoL/5/

Comment: You can create a regexp from an array, see @Amadan's answer.

Comment: This will fail for `sextant`. In fact, expanding this answer to include more curse words will cause even *more* problems.

Comment: @Rob The question was how to optimize OPs loop-based solution, not how to create a profanity filter.

Answer (score 4):

Use regexp:

```
var chatMessage = "sex it up what the fuck tits lol fuck titsss";
var badWords = ['sex', 'fUck', 'dick', 'penis', 'cum', 'tits', 'fuck'];
var regExpSource = badWords.join('|');
var regExpFilter = new RegExp(regExpSource, 'ig');

console.log(regExpFilter.test(chatMessage));
```

And remove words with asterisks like with:

```
chatMessage.replace(regExpFilter, function () {
    return '****';//Don't matter what that was a word 
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
// Prepare for search (just once)
var badWordsRE = new RegExp(badWords.join('|'), "gi");
var asterisks = "";
badWords.forEach(function(word) {
  while (word.length > asterisks.length) asterisks += "*";
});

// Search and destroy
chatMessage.replace(badWordsRE, function(word) {
  return asterisks.substring(0, word.length);
});
// => "*** it up what the **** **** lol **** ****ss"
```